# ROS driver for specific GPS receiver?

Tags: gps, roscpp, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm currently trying to set up a GPS receiver and base station my boss purchased to work in ROS.  It is a trimble Ag
GPS 542 GNSS receiver.  I tried looking online to see if there were any ROS drivers already written for this specific model, but didn't have any.  I was wondering if anyone knew of any ros drivers that might be compatible with this device, either a specific one or a more general one that could be adapted specifically for use with this receiver.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189889/ros-driver-for-specific-gps-receiver?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-12**:
Here is the info sheet: http://ssmgps.com/pdf/AGPB_AgGPS542_BaseAndReceiver_ROW_16502.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most GPS use NMEA 0183 that transmits a sentence over serial.  Does it have serial port? If it does, try this [nmea_navsat_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver).  According to this [manual](http://www.newhollandplm.com/upload/6f706cea-2732-45ae-ab8d-2239101ef5e6AG-372_UserGuide1A.pdf) it uses NMEA 0183.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-13**:
Ok, I will try this out.  Is it a problem that the project I'm going to try to integrate this into is in C++, while this package appears to be in python?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-08-13**:
Not if you are not modifying the code.  If you just use the NavSatFix msg you should be fine.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-13**:
Cool, not planning on modifying the code (provided it works as is).  However, I am encountering some setup problems that I have turned into a new question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/190089/ros-installation-and-usage-of-nmea_navsat_driver-for-gps-receiver/  If you have time do you know what I'm doing wrong in the installation?  I downloaded it with git clone but can't get catkin_make to recognize it as a new package, or to generate the actual executables I want to use.